# spring 4.3.12.RELEASE folder resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have not had time to know spring java and I have to do an Api Rest project with a webapp that uses the Api Rest all in the same project,
I am using a template for the webapp called ngx-admin that uses Angular 5+ & Typescript, Bootstrap 4+ & SCSS and others.
When compiling this project, it generates my dist folder that contains my project. This is placed in webapp / resources / * and my index calls the following ones
files:

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/inline.bundle.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/styles.bundle.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts.bundle.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/vendor.bundle.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/main.bundle.js"></script>`
```

so far so good, but my `main.bundle.js` file requires another file called`pages.module.chunk.js` and this is where my doubt is.
Because when I install it on my tomcat it does not have all the files that I have in my resources folder. I think it's a problem how to configure my project
I have read and most say that I should put the following instruction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">`

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>

    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM3cr.png)

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhdZK.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQn7z.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSy2v.png)

Comment: ¿what is your question?

Comment: @aironman How do I make everything that my resource folder be exposed?

Comment: Show your project structure hierarchy.

Comment: I uploaded some images  @MAC

Comment: It looks like you don't have all of necessary js files in resources folder, isn't? Please, take a look to this link: http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-4-mvc-static-resource-mapping-example